# Problem with Fedora 19 Gateway

Tags: networking, fedora, gateway

I have a machine that runs Fedora 19. Updating is not an option due to software constraints. I have an image that I've copied from a working unit of the exact same model using Clonezilla. I've done this before but on this latest revision of the hardware in Fedora 19 I can set a default Gateway but can't reach anything on the network. On a Fedora 25 load (can't use because of hibernation issue) my Gateway works perfectly. I've made changes to my ifcfg-enp3s0 file, stopped and restarted my network. I get a default Gateway from my static settings but I can't ping anything on the network. If I allow it to use DHCP I do not get an IP address. On the same machine I can restore Fedora 25 or boot from a live Fedora 32 version and get network. It's something with the Fedora 19 that's the issue.

Comment: Are you able to update the base system and run your constrained software in a container? Fedora Linux 19 was released _over a decade ago_..

Comment: You might try using RHEL 7 container, since RHEL 7 was based on Fedora Linux 19 and 20. That is also pretty old, though, and the latest RHEL 7 goes EOL in June 2024.

Comment: This isn't a virtual machine it's a networked device. I realize Fedora 19 is past is EOL but unfortunately running anything newer I run into other issues like the screen timing out and not able to get it back.

Comment: Can you describe the device in more detail? You don't need virtualization to run software in containers.